# can you do multiple Salesforce deployments, putting most users in the cheaper one and a few in one with best features?

Tags: salesforce, crm

since Salesforce requires high per user payment for the deployment with some advanced features, have there been attempts to get the advanced features (which are probably less likely to be needed in day to day work than the basic ones) in a separate deployment with few users and transfer in the data from the cheaper basic deployment actually used by most employees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use similar scheme to sync data from a subsidiary instance before we bring them up to the full feature instance. Jitterbit 4 has salesforce connectors which allow very easy creation of sync tasks (query/upsert, but even without the wizards its easy to use sf api service), you just need to chain pairs of operations (one web service call to load data from source, another to upset at destination using source record ID as external ID in destination).